# Matching characters preg_match PHP

Tags: php

Id like to accept alphanumeric characters and these: `!@#$%^&*()_-=+{}[]\|'"/?.>,<~€` and reject the backtick: **`**

Would this be a way to do it?

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+!@#$%^&*()_-=+{}[]\|'"/?.>,<~€ /", $message)) {}
```

Comment: You definitely need to escape the " inside the regex with \". If you just want to reject the backtick you can simplify the regex to "/[^`]/"

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fO3zD8/2

Comment: @colburton I need to match the characters and symbols and only reject the backtick.

Comment: If you only want to reject the back tick then just check if that is present. There are numerous errors with your regex, PHP as well. `if (preg_match("/\`/"`

Comment: @chris85 I want to reject the backtick. But also validate the rest...so all of them have to be in the regex. I know there are errors

Comment: @RobbieAverill newb to this so super lost with the site.

Comment: This `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` is allowing alpha characters and numbers.

Comment: @chris85 I know that much...but I also want to allow `!@#$%^&*()_-=+{}[]\|'"/?.>,<~€` except for the backtick.

Comment: The `[]` is a character class, you list all characters your want to allow inside that. Certain characters need to be escaped or positioned differently. http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: @RobbieAverill I saw the link, thanks. Could something like this work that will include alphanumerics and reject the backtick `[^`][a-zA-Z0-9]([\w!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\-=\+\d{}\[\]\\|'"\/\?\.>,<~€]+)$` ?

Comment: @chris85 Is this correct then [^`][a-zA-Z0-9]([\w!@#\$%\^&*()\-=\+\d{}[]\\|'"\/\?\.>,<~€]+)$ ?

Comment: I'm not really clear what you are trying to do. Three character classes means you are allowing 3 characters. Make one character class. and use a quantifier on it. That will allow all listed characters in the string (if anchors are used.

Comment: @chris85 I want these: a-zA-Z0-9]([\w!@#\$%\^&*()\-=\+\d{}[]\\|'"\/\?\.>,<~€]+)$ to pass and only reject ` the backtick. Assuming I get this right, I will do an if condition anything thats outside of those characters including the backtick i will send to `else`.

Comment: Maybe `/^[-\w+!@#$%^&*()={}[\]\\|'"\/?.>,<~€]+$/`. Try your strings out with: https://regex101.com/r/wQ1gM7/1

Comment: @chris85 Will this include `a-zA-Z0-9` and exclude the backtick: ` ?

Comment: Inside the `[]` are all the characters you want. `\w` is `a-zA-Z0-9_`. Since the backtick is not in the allowed list if it is present it will make the test fail. The anchors ensure a full string match. Add `\s` if you want spaces, tabs, and new lines as well. If only spaces and tabs use `\h`.

Comment: @chris85 Thats for the explanation. Someone above suggested this [^`], what is a way to merge them together?

Comment: You don't merge them. It is one or the other. It would be `/^[^\`]+$/` which says there is not one backtick in the string. So every other character is allowed.

Comment: @chris85 I see. So would have to run the string twice to validate then, correct?

Comment: Why? They are doing the same thing. Neither allows a backtick. You either can explicitly state the characters you want, or block the character(s) you don't...or you can do some mash up but I don't see why that is needed.

Comment: @chris85 The backtick gets rejected like you said. However it also rejects the back slash \. Can that be added in somehow?

Comment: Are you in double quotes or single quotes? Oh, double, use three backslashes, not 2. I think it gets difficult at this point, one is for the PHP escaping and one is for the regex escaping, so I think 3 is right. (if it were single quotes it'd be 2).

Comment: @chris85 Is this what you mean: `'/^([-\w\s+!@#$%^&*()={}[\]\\\|\'"\/?.>,<~€]+)$/'` ?

Comment: Only 2 `/` in single quotes, 3 in double. https://regex101.com/r/mG8nS7/1 This is how a regex renders it. PHP renders the backslash though in double quotes as an escape character as well.